# Can i share one sql database with SQLiteOpenHelper in android with two apps?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqliteopenhelper

I have two applications. One is main worker and other one is watchdog.
I want to check first clock with other one... `(clock is just incrementing number in DB record)`...
so I'm writing clock status in DB with `SQLiteOpenHelper` and want to check it with watchdog application...

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: by using a custom `ContentProvider`

Comment: thanks. ill dig in to it.